# How to Delete duplicate rows without Primary key

Tags: sql, delete-row

The following table has no primary key, I would like to delete the duplicate rows from the following table. The only differentiating factor in the duplicate rows is atom_id2. How do I delete that duplicate row. Please do give your suggestions.

```
atom_id1, atom_id2, atom_ty1, atom_ty2, lennard_jones_acoef, lennard_jones_bcoef 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1,        1,        N3,       N3,       9.44293233E+05,      8.01323529E+02
1,        2,        N3,       H,        2.12601181E+03,      2.09604198E+01
1,        3,        N3,       H,        2.12601181E+03,      2.09604198E+01
1,        4,        N3,       H,        2.12601181E+03,      2.09604198E+01  <-Duplicate Row
1,        5,        N3,       CX,       9.95480466E+05,      7.36907417E+02
1,        6,        N3,       HP,       2.01791425E+04,      6.45756063E+01
1,        7,        N3,       CT,       9.95480466E+05,      7.36907417E+02
1,        8,        N3,       HC,       8.96776989E+04,      1.36131731E+02
1,        9,        N3,       HC,       8.96776989E+04,      1.36131731E+02 <---- Duplicate Row
1,        10,       N3,       C,        8.82619071E+05,      6.53361429E+02
1,        11,       N3,       O2,       6.06829342E+05,      6.77220874E+02
```

Comment: Create PK, find duplicates, delete them

Comment: what DBMS are you using?

Comment: @zerkms: what If table already contains IDENTITY column ? in that case PK cannot be created.

Answer (score 2):

Without a primary key, you'll need to provide *additional criteria* to ensure you *delete* the appropriate record.

You can do so with the `WHERE` clause, for example:

```
DELETE FROM your_table WHERE atom_id1 = 1 AND atom_id2 = 4;
```

**Note:** This assumes there are no other records than those you provided. I strongly suggest running this as a `SELECT` first.

You should also consider creating a primary key. Seems as though `atom_id2` might be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

```
First you get distinct row insert temp.. table then delete current table and import row from temp.. table.

insert into temp_table(column1,column2,..) 
select distinct column1,column2,... from table2

delete from table2

insert into table2(column1,column2,..) 
select column1,column2,... from temp_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Primary Key is the best method. In you case, use atleast two fields in where condition including atom_id2, so that no duplicate will be selected. This you have to confirm first by creating an appropriate `SELECT` statement and then convert this statement to `DELETE` which will be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you find difficulty in deleting duplicate rows in the existing table,you can create new table and insert the distinct values from the existing table. i hope it will help u